# Ubuntu 16.04 always shutdown on Dell XPS 13 9350

Tags: dell, overheating, fan, 16.04

Because Ubuntu 15.10 has no wifi driver for xps 13 9350, I install 16.04 beta 1 on it with removing windows. Unfortunately, when use browser to open web site, after a few minutes, mouse stop, then hear the noise of fan become louder, finally system shutdown. When launching the system again, see some error information:

`Error Code:0711
Validation Code:115480
Service Tag:CGRBM72`

The Dell Support Assist site has following description

Failure Description:System detected repeated thermal trips due to excessive heat.

Recommendations:Inspect the system for clogged or obstructed air vents. Make sure that BIOS is current and rerun the diagnostics.

After reinstall Ubuntu 16.04 final beta yesterday, the problem still exists.
My bios is newest 1.2.3. Do not know how to find out the real reason.

Comment: Do you have this issue in other operating systems?

Comment: Any specific reason why you are installing 16.04 beta? It's better to stick to  14.04LTS or 15.10(at least somewhat stable version). Seems to be overheating issue - best advise is to reach out to Dell support. You can refer to what Mathew Smith mentioned so that you can find the temperature using lm-sensors or xsensor etc...

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04 is still under development and is buggy. There is no support for it anywhere including this website

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I change to ArchLinux and use xfce(its' lighter and will not cause too much cpu loading). Now using browser to read wiki will not cause laptop dead. I guess the Linux driver does not support XPS13 9350 well because the laptop is too new, it needs time. But with xfce, the temperature is not too high like before. This way gives me time to wait, a better kernel or better ubuntu version.

Answer (score 0):

Read the failure description, your laptop is overheating.

You can install the `lm-sensors` package to monitor the temperature of your system.

The best way to do this is with the `watch` command, for live updates. For example:

```
$ watch -n 1 sensors
```